# Viewing different stats on 2nd tableview controller

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

beginner swift coder.

I created a table view of basketball teams on my view controller.  After that, I created a nav controller for the view controller.  I entered 7 basketball teams to my table view.  Now, I have created a second view controller, so that when I tap on any of the 7 basketball teams, it will open another window.

My question is, how do I display different information when tapping on different basketball teams?

enter image description here[Main View controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMEy2.jpg)

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
var nbaMusic: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

let nbateams = ["Knicks", "Cavaliers", "Thunder", "Warriors", "Lakers", "Bulls", "Magic"]

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nbateams.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell:UITableViewCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("nba", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    myCell.textLabel?.text = nbateams[indexPath.row]

    myCell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: nbateams[indexPath.row])

    return myCell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let data = nbateams[indexPath.row]
    let playerView = playerViewController()
    detailView.dicData = data
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(playerView, animated: true)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
    let nbaMusicURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Roundball_Rock", ofType: "mp3")!)
    do{
        nbaMusic = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: nbaMusicURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
    }
    catch  _ {
        return print("File not found")
    }
    nbaMusic.numberOfLoops = 0
    nbaMusic.prepareToPlay()
    nbaMusic.play()
```

class playerViewController: UIViewController {

```
let knicks = ["Carmelo.png"]
let Cavaliers = ["Lebron.png"]

@IBOutlet var playerInfoView: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var playerImage: UIImageView!
var imageView: String?
var dicData: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playerImage.image = UIImage(named: dicData!)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MainViewController: 
viewDidLoad you set more:

```
myTableView.delegate = self
```

and  implement:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let data = nbateams[indexPath.row]
    let playerView = playerViewController() // or load from storyboad
    playerView.dicData = data
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(playerView, animated: true)
}
```

in playerViewController create a data object, and transfer data(info need display) to it

```
@IBOutlet var playerInfoView: UILabel!



@IBOutlet var playerImage: UIImageView!
var imageView: String?
var dicData: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playerImage.image = UIImage(named: dicData) // ex

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try it out when I get home today.

Comment: Sorry, I tried what you suggested but I still having trouble understanding this.  I wasn't able to get this to work :*(

Comment: I have posted the code, hopefully I did something right :)

Comment: and basketballDetailView , plz

Comment: I called the 2nd view controller "playerViewController" but that's where i'm having the issue.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it out when I get home.  From your code, it seems to be making some sense to me.

Comment: It seems like detailView.dicData = data is telling me there is an error - "use of unresolved identifier 'detailView'.

Comment: I updated the playerViewController above with the data object you suggested, hopefully what I did was correct :)

Comment: :), my failse . i fixed